# Hide passwords in logs

Tags: karate

The following code :

```
Background:
    * url "https://www.google.fr"

    Scenario: hide password
        Given path "login"
        And form field username = 'john'
        And form field password = 'secret'
        When method post
        Then status 200
```

Gives the following output :

```
10:38:34.710 request:
1 > POST https://www.google.fr/login
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 29
1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: www.google.fr
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_191)
username=john&password=secret
```

Is there a way to hide the password here, while keeping the logs at the DEBUG level? If that means also hiding the username, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may need to be a feature request if [`* configure report = { showLog: false }`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity) does not do it already.

Comment: Thank you for that. One good thing is that I can hide only the request I want (the authentication) by using this command inside the scenario itself. The password still appears in the console output though, even if it is excluded from the report. Should I create a feature request for this?

Comment: For anyone finding this question, here's the request : https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/699